# Yosemite Apple Brown highlight color

Tags: macos

Is it possible to find the RGB values of the "Apple Brown" highlight color Apple introduced in Yosemite?

Comment: in what app is that ?

Comment: Go to System Preferences => General

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use builtin app called **Digital Color Meter.app** which can be found in `/Applications/Utilities`. It'll show You **RGB** values. You can copy them as text with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Take an screenshot of your screen (<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) where you can see this colour.

Then with photoshop (pixelmator and others have same option) use a tool called `Eyedropper tool`. This tool picks the color where you click on the image, and left it as foreground in color picker. Doble click in the color and your have it.

[image: Eyedropper tool]

Answer (score 0):

#eddeca, or RGB(237, 222, 202)